# Grabbing email for Custom Profile Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am looking for a way to grab the email of the person that clicks on the %%profile_url%% to access the custom profile center I am building. I have every other functionality working by grabbing the email from the URL, but we have removed the email from the URL, so that is why I am looking to grab it some other way.

All I need to accomplish is just grabbing their email and storing it in a variable I can use to populate some fields and then possibly update it in the future. Either it be by using AMPscript or SSJS that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The %%profile_url%% is a brand tag that can only be changed by support. You can simply request they change the value of that tag to point to your url with a parameter for email address like this https://web.myurl.com?email=%%emailaddr%%.

Then on your custom profile center landing page you can use the RequestParameter AMPscript function to retrieve the email address like so:

```
%%[set @email = RequestParameter("email")]%%
```